# Google Tables - How do I remove square brackets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

For example, I have this in cell A11:

[dbo].[monthReport_CALC_An_Multi_Coke]

And I want to remove ALL the brackets to make it work:

dbo.monthReport_CALC_An_Multi_Core

I found a few functions, but they only remove the first bracket.

I need a function that will remove all the brackets.

Can someone provide me with one? I'm new to Google Sheets, so my knowledge of the features is very limited. So please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either of these two functions:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1, "[", ""), "]", "")
```

or

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1, "\[|\]", "")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution:

```cpp
=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"[][]",)
```

[image]